# Знак градуса: слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, пробелы, знак

Как пишутся такие сочетания, как:

`30°; 180°; 360° и т. д.`?

Или, может, так:

`30 °; 180 °; 360 ° и т. д.`?

То есть «°» стоит писать слитно с числами или раздельно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такие сочетания пишутся без пробела: ***30°; 180°; 360°***.

[**Знаки №, %, §, ° с пробелом**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC/):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[**Знак градуса**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0) (°):

> По правилам типографского набора знак градуса ставится сразу после числового обозначения величины размерности угла или температуры без всякого пробела, однако если в случае с температурой указывается также шкала, по которой производится измерение (по Цельсию, по Фаренгейту и т. п.), знак градуса отбивается от числовой величины неразрывным пробелом...

Comment: А если так: 100 000( °)? Число уюе содержит пробел. Сам знак пробелом отбиваться не будет? Это просто пример, если что.

Comment: @Максим  Думаю, что нет. Но ведь всё это касается именно типографских отбивок, там используются совсем другие расстояния (кегли, полукегли или что-то в этом роде, не помню точно) между разными символами. А у нас (в компьютере) клавиатура позволяет ставить только одинаковые проблелы, что иногда может выглядеть слишком "длинно". Поэтому не заморачивайтесь, это не очень принципиально. Я напишу так:  *–100 000 градусов; –100 000°*.